# Java: library that does nice formatted log outputs

Tags: java, logging, log4j, slf4j

I cannot find back a library that allowed to format log output statements in a much nicer way than what is usually seen. One of the feature I remember is that it could 'offset' the log message depending on the 'nestedness' of where the log statement was occuring.

That is, instead of this:

```
DEBUG | DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java| 86 | Loading bean definitions
DEBUG | AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java| 411 | Finished creating instance of bean 'MS-SQL'
DEBUG | DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java| 213 | Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'MySQL'
DEBUG | AutowireCapableBeanFactory.java| 383 | Creating instance of bean 'MySQL'
DEBUG | AutowireCapableBeanFactory.java| 459 | Eagerly caching bean 'MySQL' to allow for resolving potential circular references
DEBUG | AutowireCapableBeanFactory.java| 789 | Another debug message
```

It would shows something like this:

```
DEBUG | DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java| 86  | Loading bean definitions
DEBUG | AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java | 411 | Finished creating instance of bean 'MS-SQL'
DEBUG | DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java       | 213 | Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'MySQL'
DEBUG | AutowireCapableBeanFactory.java         | 383 | Creating instance of bean 'MySQL'
DEBUG | AutowireCapableBeanFactory.java         | 459 | |__ Eagerly caching bean 'MySQL' to allow for resolving potential circular references
DEBUG | AutowireCapableBeanFactory.java         | 789 |     |__ Another debug message
```

This is an example I just made up (*VeryLongCamelCaseClassNamesNotMine*). But I remember seeing such cleanly formatted log output and they were really much nicer than anything I had seen before and, in addition to being just plain nicer, they were also easier to read for they reproduced some of the logical organization of the code.

Yet I cannot find anymore what that library was.

I'm pretty sure it was fully compatible with *log4j* or *sl4j*.

Comment: Have you looked at log4j's PatternLayout? Seems like it covers the formatting you want. http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PatternLayout.html

Comment: @marklai: +1 at your comment, it's interesting in that apparently it can pad, but I'm really after a library/API that exists (for Java) but that I simply can't find anymore.  And it does the "logging according to indent level" thinggamagic. I'm trying snap.com in visual mode to find back the project's webpage but simply can't find it :(

Comment: Not sure what the library is, but you should probably watch out for a performance hit. If the library indents stuff by itself, it's probably using the stack to be able to calculate how deep it has to indent. The problem is that to get the stack, it has to throw an exception, catch it and get the stack trace from there. This is probably how log4j outputs the invoked method name and it warns against serious performance problems as well (http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PatternLayout.html).

Comment: @Tomislav Nakic-Alfirevic: yup that is a very good point... But I'd still love to find that API back :)

Comment: How exactly would a logging framework know how to indent certain statements ?

Answer (score 1):

I see two things in your code samples:

1. Padding of the classnames according to the longest name
2. Messages modified depending on the "nesting".

For 1. I hardly see how this can be done, since you never know which class *will* log in the future. Sure, you can add padding according to the longest class name that *has* ever *been* logged, but the file will not look as nice as your sample once a longer class name is logged.

For 2. One could implement a filter (see [here](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/filters.html) for logback documentation about filter) that would study the caller data and add some kind of "is nested in" prefix like you wrote in your example. This would not be too hard a task, I guess.

Hope this helps... although I do not provide you with the link to the lib you are looking for... :-(

Comment: I cant figure out why the log contains .java with the class names...its not like it helps.